# How to disable Yarn web UI / Rest API?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am quite new in yarn and I hope to disable only the resource manager web app. The YARN web app in our hadoop cluster has security vulnerability detected by https://github.com/vulhub/vulhub/blob/master/hadoop/unauthorized-yarn/exploit.py.

Actually we are using our cluster for storage, not for running MR jobs so yarn web UI and API are not necessary. So I hope to disable the web UI/API but I couldn't find any way to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you only use HDFS, then why install YARN? What is stopping you from terminating the ResourceManager/NodeManager?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to secure the API so you aren't exposed:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/HttpAuthentication.html